# Visual Basic Assigning an object as a property of another object

Tags: vba

I am trying to set the data of an object called valvePos1_. It's method called SetData takes three parameters: a String, a Buckle object, and a PostTop object. When the code reaches the Buckle or PostTop objects, I get a Type Mismatch error.

In the parent function:

```
Dim valvePos1_, valvePos6_, valvePos11_ As ValvePosition
Set valvePos1_ = New ValvePosition
Dim postTop1_, postTop6_, postTop11_ As PostTop
Set postTop1_ = New PostTop
Dim buckle1_, buckle6_, buckle11_ As Buckle
Set buckle1_ = New Buckle

....

Call valvePos1_.SetData(Cells(iRows, 2), buckle1_, postTop1_) 'first param is a String
```

In the ValvePosition class

```
Private iPosition As Integer 'position
Dim buckle_ As Buckle 'the Buckle
Dim postTop_ As PostTop 'the PostTop


'Sets all the data
Public Sub SetData(posi As Integer, buck As Buckle, pt As PostTop)

    iPosition = posi
    buckle_ = buck
    postTop_ = pt

End Sub 'end SetData
```

Comment: You need to use `Set` when assigning a value to an object variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) use `Set` keyword when assigning a value to objects:

```
Set buckle_ = buck 
Set postTop_ = pt
```

2) when declaring

```
Dim postTop1_, postTop6_, postTop11_ As PostTop
```

only `postTop11_` declared as type `PostTop`, while `postTop1_, postTop6_` are `Variant`. Delcare them explicitly: `Dim postTop1_ As PostTop, postTop6_ As PostTop, postTop11_ As PostTop`.
The same thing for `Dim valvePos1_, valvePos6_, valvePos11_ As ValvePosition` and
`Dim buckle1_, buckle6_, buckle11_ As Buckle`